# How to shrink (Rasperry PI) IMG file with the same data

Tags: filesystems, partition, raspberry-pi

I have an IMG file with the following structure:

```
$ fdisk -l myimage.img 
Disk myimage.img: 6,1 GiB, 6512705536 bytes, 12720128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x244b8248

Device                                     Boot   Start      End Sectors Size Id Type
myimage.img1         8192   137215  129024  63M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
myimage.img2       137216  8525823 8388608   4G 83 Linux
myimage.img3      8525824 12720127 4194304   2G 83 Linux
```

It contains bootable Rasperry Pi image.

If I mount these partitions with

```
$ mount -o loop,offset=4194304,sizelimit=66060288 myimage.img myimage.img1
$ mount -o loop,offset=70254592,sizelimit=4294967296 myimage.img myimage.img2
$ mount -o loop,offset=4365221888,sizelimit=2147483648 myimage.img myimage.img3
```

I get

```
$ du -sh myimage.img1
22M myimage.img1
$ du -sh myimage.img2
1,7G    myimage.img2
$ du -sh myimage.img3
306M    myimage.img3
```

I.e. actual data in partitions is much smaller. Can I shrink image file to smaller size (around ~2G here) and get the same partiotion structure from it with smaller time? Currently it takes ~10 minutes for me to burn this image onto cheap flash card.

Comment: How do you do the burning? Via `dd`? If so: do you use the `conv=sparse` option which should take care of this? How did you create the image?

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you're doing, so this may not fit your needs, BUT since you're using RPi, you may want to consider creating your image files with the `image-backup` utility. There's a [Q&A that has the details.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is *not* copying the empty parts of the image. (It's really that simple.) Typically, you **want** the partitions to span the whole card – otherwise there's unusable space.

If you've downloaded this image, then the easiest solution is probably using `sudo dd if=myimage.img of=/dev/devicename conv=sparse`; that will detect when copying completely zero blocks, and not copy them, and instead just "jump" forward.

But to answer your question: yes, you can probably just mount these partions, copy the data off, modify the partition table to contain smaller partitions, make the same file systems there, copy the files back, and truncate the overall image file. It's just not very likely a good idea, compared to dealing with unused space properly.

Note that your average writing speed, should you actually be copying the whole 6.1 GB, is 10 MB/s – not too bad for a cheap SD card, actually! So, maybe you're *not* copying the whole image, but only the non-zero parts already. In that case, only *compression* could help (but "How do I compress file systems" would quickly lead very very much further – and we know nothing about your image's contents).

(if you're *building* an image yourself, make sure you use a sparse file to begin with – and then use tools like `bmap` to ship and burn sparse versions!)